# What is the meaning of "earthy"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dictionaries

> Earthy : referring to sex and the human body in a direct way Example:
>
> She has an earthy sense of humor.

I don't understand the example with the meaning.
I got this from [Cambridge Dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/earthy_1?q=earthy)

Comment: Me either.  I found this description on [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/earthy): "*British English: earthy* If you describe someone as earthy, you mean that they are open and direct, and talk about subjects which other people avoid or feel ashamed about. *ADJECTIVE* She is a very physical young woman, earthy, and very intense."  Maybe that's it?

Comment: It is defined as a crude or unrefined sense of humor. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earthy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you,taken from Vocabulary.com

**"The adjective earthy runs the gamut from "crunchy" to "crude." You could use earthy to describe bohemian fashion or a vulgar comedian. Just don't use it to describe our planet."*

*You could use it in a more literal way, like the "earthy smell" coming from the vegetable garden. Or, you could use it in a more figurative way — like to describe someone who wears Birkenstock sandals and grows her own bean sprouts.*

***Earthy can also be used to describe someone who tends to be gross or vulgar, but this use of the word is somewhat euphemistic.***

*Definitions:

- *hearty and lusty (“an earthy enjoyment of life”)*
- *conspicuously and tastelessly indecent ("an earthy sense of humor”).*
- *sensible and practical ("her earthy common sense")***

For more info,Please refer to this [link](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/earthy)..

Comment: +1 An excellent link. But it would be a good idea to sum up what it says; if the link dies at some point, the answer will still be here for future readers.

Answer (score -2):

earthy comes from the word earth... the only LOGICAL definition for earthy.. or earthiness is for someone or something that is down to earth.. earthy, based and structured from the essences of nature and natural aspects.. its rather a lovely word originated from the lovely word of " earth "